# Transfer from two dimensional array to vector

Tags: c++, arrays

My goal is to create a vector of type "TeamS" which is TeamV. TeamV should have 4 sections for data. Ex: TeamV[0] = teamID, member1, member2, member3.
I found a way to get the array of ids and distribute to TeamV vector. But I cant distribute 3 team members at the same time. What should i do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
const int NUM_TEAMS = 4;
const int NUM_MEMBERS = 3;

struct TeamS{
   int ID;
   string teamMembers[3];
};


void Initialize (vector <TeamS> & TeamV, const int id[],
             const string m[][NUM_MEMBERS], int arraySize){
for (int i = 0; i<NUM_TEAMS;i++){
    for (int x=0; x<NUM_TEAMS;x++){
        for (int y = 0; y<NUM_MEMBERS;y++){
            TeamV.push_back({id[i],m[x][y]});
        }
      }
   }
 }


int main(){

vector <TeamS> TeamV; //content of arrays below should go in to this vector

const int ID [NUM_TEAMS] ={ 123, 321, 456, 789};
const string MEMBERS [NUM_TEAMS] [NUM_MEMBERS ] =
{
    {"Sarah", "Joe", "John"},
    {"Chris", "Kevin", "James"},
    {"Tom", "Kim", "Emily"},
    {"Jill", "Jason", "Jim"}
};

Initialize(TeamV, ID, MEMBERS, NUM_TEAMS*NUM_MEMBERS);
}
```

Comment: What you should do is initialize the array member as `{a, b, c}`.

Comment: Like [this](https://ideone.com/q4YsvQ)? Or do you necessarily want to copy arbitrary arrays?

Comment: I think you made a mistake here: `TeamV.push_back({id[i],m[x][y]})`. You push_back the ID and 1 team member (x and y position) although the TeamS struct expects 3 team members. So the solution of @Drop is good as he passes the TeamS struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Inistialize should look like.

```
void Initialize (vector <TeamS> & TeamV, const int id[],
                 const string m[][NUM_MEMBERS], int arraySize){
  TeamV.resize(NUM_TEAMS);
  for (int i = 0; i<NUM_TEAMS;++i) {
    TeamV[i].ID = id[i];
    for (int y = 0; y<NUM_MEMBERS;++y){
      TeamV[i].teamMembers[y] = m[i][y];
    }
  }
}
```

But have you considered, that you really should be looking at `std::unordered_map<unsigned, std::vector<std::string>>` instead?